# How to decompose a number sequence into convergent subsequences?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a real number sequence. Let $I$ be a subset of $\mathbb N_+$, use the symbol $\{a_n\}_I$ to denote the subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ indexed by $I$. Does there exist a countable family of subsets $I_1,I_2,\cdots \subseteq \mathbb N_+$, that $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^\infty I_n=\mathbb N_+$, and for every $i\neq j$, $I_i\cap I_j=\emptyset$, and $\forall i\in \mathbb N_+$, $\{a_n\}_{I_i}$ is a convergent sequence? We consider divergent to positive or negative infinity as a special type of convergence.

If in general it doesn't exist, which condition we need for $\{a_n\}$ for its existence?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a real sequence, we can have only the following three situations:

(1) the sequence is convergent,

(2) the sequence diverges to $\pm \infty$.

(3) the sequence is bounded but not convergent (i.e. oscillates between a set of values)

Case 1. If the sequence is convergent, then we can consider
$$
I_p \colon=  \{ p, p^2, p^3, \cdots \}
$$
for all primes $p$.

Case 2. If the sequence diverges to $\pm \infty$, then we can assume that some monotonic subsequence diverges to $\pm \infty$, and in that case we can of consider the sets
$I_p$ of Case 1 for such a monotonically divergent subsequence.

Case 3. If our sequence is bounded but not convergent, then we can consider it to be a sequence in some closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$ on the real line for some real numbers $a$ abd $b$ such that $a < b$. Since our sequence is in the compact metric space $[a, b]$, therefore this sequence necessarily has a convergent subsequence. Now we apply Case 1 to this convergent subsequence.

Thus what you're asking for is always possible.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It may be better to put $a_1$ in front of your subsequence in every case. It doesn't change the convergence, but it avoids such a situation: in the construction, the union of all $I_n$ is not $\mathbb N_+$, when some elements of the $\{a_n\}$ are always not be selected into subsequences.

Comment: There's (4): the combination of  (2) and (3). (something like $a_n = n$ for $n$ even and $a_n = (-1)^{n+1/2}$ for $n$ odd).